# can't run CMD command through Python win32Process.Create Process

Tags: python, pywin32

This one drive me crazy as I try to solve it for 3 days now with no success.

I have a python script that automate some stuff, one of its main objectives is to run cmd commands whenever the user want this (User want to print something to console) as an example

`PyH1,PyH2,i1,i2 = win32process.CreateProcess(None,Command ,None,None,1,\
                                             CreationFlag,\
                                             None,None,PySTARTUPINFO)`

give me this error `pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')`

I am Just sending "echo Hello World" to the cmd through python **command** variable in the CreateProcess second argument.

My Operating system is **Win7(x64)**

Python Version : **Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
on win32**

I tried to reinstall Pywin (32 & 64) both didn't work, and I am confused, which file dosen't exist, as I don't supply or need any!!

I tried to include cmd path in Windows Environment variables with no succss.

I tried to include a path to notepad instead of my original echo hello world, it works and opened notepad normally, so CreateProcess is not damaged for any reason.

I hav another Python version on my machine 
**Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32**

Where should I look, is it some 64/32 bit issue or more than that!

I really apprecite help at that one, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `cmd.exe` as first argument to `CreateProcess` and `/c "echo Hello world"` as second

Or leave 1st as `None` and pass to second full cmd line: `cmd.exe /c "echo Hello world"`